# Extract specific values (n digit long and starting with a number) PSQL

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have two string like this and I want to extract 6 digits starting from "2007" using postgresql. Please help

```
"472a62b98b-2004-07-l-de_k-de_n-email_t-cus_200703"
"21d6bd96f2-2004-04-l-de_c-de_m-email_t-cus_200705-b"
```

Results would be:

```
"200703"
"200705"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` with a regex:

```
substring(the_column from '2007[0-9]{2}')
```

This extracts the first substring that starts with `2007` and is followed by (exactly) two digits.

Comment: Works! what does {2} stands for?

Comment: exactly two repetitions. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-SYNTAX-DETAILS